# Add CSS class to Html.ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-views

I want to style a link in my page and am using Html.ActionLink to create the link.  The problem is I don't know how to style the resulting link.  How do I add a CSS class to the Html.ActionLink in order to style it?

Comment: maybe this link help you [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1245858.aspx/1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Html.ActionLink("Link Name", 
                "ActionName",
                "ControllerName",
                null,
                new { @class = "myCssClass" }
                )
```

Comment: this doesn't give the resulting anchor tag a class but passing class as a parameter to the ActionName action.

Comment: @SachinKainth Sorry I missed a parameter out! Please try again

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password ?", "ViewName","ControlerName",null, new { @class="Link"})
```

Add Link class is `<head>` tag

```
<style type="text/css">
        .Link
        {
            margin-bottom:20px;
            color:blue;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
```